# Calculating children value base on parent value in Oracle (MRP)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table named `ORDERS` that contains a list of products and ordered quantities :

```
ORDER N° | PRODUCT | QUANTITY
1        | BICYCLE | 10
2        | BICYCLE | 3
3        | CAR     | 2
...
```

Another table named `COMPOSITION` holds a list of all the components of the products in the first table in a hierarchical manner.

```
PRODUCT      | COMPONENT        | FACTOR
BICYCLE      | FRAME            | 1
FRAME        | ALUMINUM BARS    | 12
BICYCLE      | DRIVING UNIT     | 1
DRIVING UNIT | SMALL GEAR       | 1
DRIVING UNIT | BIG GEAR         | 1
DRIVING UNIT | CHAIN            | 1
DRIVING UNIT | PEDALS SET       | 2
PEDALS SET   | PEDALS           | 1
PEDALS SET   | SCREWS           | 4
...
```

This means that a bicycle is made of 1 frame which in turn is made of 12 aluminum bars. Every bicycle is also made from 1 driving unit, each of which is made 1 small and 1 big gear, 1 chain and 2 pedals set and every pedal set is made of 1 pedal and 4 screws.

For simplification purposes, the example provided is just for the bicycle but the table holds components for all the available products and the number of levels in each hierarchy varies from one product to another.

I have a third table named `STOCK` that contains the stocks of each of the components that are mentioned in the previous table.

```
COMPONENT     | STOCK
BICYCLE       | 2
FRAME         | 5
ALUMINUM BARS | 26
DRIVING UNIT  | 7
...
PEDALS SET    | 0
PEDALS        | 5
SCREWS        | 10
```

I want to use an SQL query to identify how much of every component is missing to fulfill the orders.

Calculation example :

```
Quantity ordered of bicycles 10 + 3 = 13
Missing quantity of bicycles = 13 - 2 (stock) = 11
Missing quantity of frames = 11 * 1 (1 per bicycle) - 5 (stock) = 6
...
Missing quantity of driving units = 11 * 1 (1 per bicycle) - 7 (stock) = 4
Missing quantity of pedals sets 4 * 2 (2 per driving unit) - 0 (stock) = 8
Missing quantity of pedals = 8 * 1 (1 per pedals set) - 5 (stock) = 3
Missing quantity of screws = 8 * 4 (4 per pedals set) - 10 (stock) = 22
...
```

So the final table would look like :

```
COMPONENT    | MISSING
FRAMES       | 6
...
DRIVING UNIT | 4
PEDALS SET   | 8
PEDALS       | 3
SCREWS       | 22
...
```

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE composition ( PRODUCT, COMPONENT, FACTOR ) AS
SELECT 'BICYCLE',       'FRAME',            1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'FRAME',         'ALUMINUM BARS',    12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BICYCLE',       'DRIVING UNIT',     1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DRIVING UNIT',  'SMALL GEAR',       1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DRIVING UNIT',  'BIG GEAR',         1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DRIVING UNIT',  'CHAIN',            1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DRIVING UNIT',  'PEDALS SET',       2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PEDALS SET',    'PEDALS',           1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PEDALS SET',    'SCREWS',           4 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE orders ( ORDER_NO, PRODUCT, QUANTITY ) AS
SELECT 1, 'BICYCLE', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'BICYCLE', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'CAR',     2 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE stock ( COMPONENT, STOCK ) AS
SELECT 'BICYCLE',       2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'FRAME',         5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ALUMINUM BARS', 26 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DRIVING UNIT',  7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PEDALS SET',    0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PEDALS',        5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SCREWS',        10 FROM DUAL;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE stock_pkg IS
  TYPE composition_table IS TABLE OF COMPOSITION%ROWTYPE;

  FUNCTION path(
    root    IN COMPOSITION.PRODUCT%TYPE,
    leaf    IN COMPOSITION.COMPONENT%TYPE
  ) RETURN composition_table PIPELINED;

  FUNCTION calculateFactor(
    root    IN COMPOSITION.PRODUCT%TYPE,
    stop_at IN COMPOSITION.PRODUCT%TYPE,
    leaf    IN COMPOSITION.COMPONENT%TYPE
  ) RETURN NUMBER;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY stock_pkg
IS
  FUNCTION path(
    root    IN COMPOSITION.PRODUCT%TYPE,
    leaf    IN COMPOSITION.COMPONENT%TYPE
  ) RETURN composition_table PIPELINED
  IS
    CURSOR cur IS
      SELECT up.product,
             up.component,
             up.factor
      FROM   (
        SELECT c.*, ROWID AS rid
        FROM   composition c
        START WITH product = root
        CONNECT BY product = PRIOR component
      ) up
      INNER JOIN
      (
        SELECT ROWID AS rid
        FROM   composition
        START WITH component = leaf
        CONNECT BY PRIOR product = component
      ) down
      ON ( up.RID = down.RID );

    r_composition COMPOSITION%ROWTYPE;
  BEGIN
    OPEN cur;

    LOOP
      FETCH cur INTO r_composition;
      EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
      PIPE ROW( r_composition );
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_NEEDED THEN
      CLOSE cur;
      RAISE;
  END;

  FUNCTION calculateFactor(
    root    IN COMPOSITION.PRODUCT%TYPE,
    stop_at IN COMPOSITION.PRODUCT%TYPE,
    leaf    IN COMPOSITION.COMPONENT%TYPE
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
    factor COMPOSITION.FACTOR%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT COALESCE( ROUND(EXP(SUM(LN(factor)))), 1 )
    INTO   factor
    FROM   TABLE( stock_pkg.path( root, leaf ) )
    START WITH component = leaf AND component != stop_at
    CONNECT BY PRIOR product = component AND component != stop_at;

    RETURN factor;
  END;
END;
/
```

**Query**:

```
WITH comp AS (
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( product ) AS root,
         component,
         stock_pkg.calculateFactor(
           root    => CONNECT_BY_ROOT( product ),
           stop_at => CONNECT_BY_ROOT( product ),
           leaf    => component
         ) AS total_factor
  FROM   composition c
  START WITH product IN ( SELECT product FROM orders )
  CONNECT BY PRIOR component = product
UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT
         product,
         product,
         1
  FROM   orders
)
,multipliers AS (
  SELECT root,
         COALESCE( p.product, c.component ) AS product,
         c.component,
         c.total_factor,
         stock_pkg.calculateFactor( c.root, p.product, c.component ) AS multiplier
  FROM   comp c,
         TABLE( stock_pkg.path( c.root, c.component ) ) (+) p
)
,aggregated_stock AS (
  SELECT root,
         component,
         SUM( factored_stock ) AS aggregated_stock
  FROM   (
    SELECT m.root,
           m.component,
           s.stock * multiplier AS factored_stock
    FROM   multipliers m
           INNER JOIN
           stock s
           ON ( m.product = s.component )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.root,
           c.component,
           s.stock
    FROM   comp c
           INNER JOIN
           stock s
           ON ( c.component = s.component )
    WHERE  c.root != c.component
  )
  GROUP BY root, component
)
,total_orders AS (
  SELECT product,
        SUM( quantity ) AS quantity
  FROM   orders
  GROUP BY product
)
,required_stock AS (
  SELECT c.component,
         SUM( c.total_factor * o.quantity ) AS total_quantity
  FROM   comp c
         INNER JOIN
         total_orders o
         ON ( c.root = o.product )
  GROUP BY c.component
)
SELECT r.component,
       r.total_quantity - COALESCE( a.aggregated_stock, 0 ) AS missing
FROM   required_stock r
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       aggregated_stock a
       ON ( r.component = a.component );
```

**Output**:

```
COMPONENT        MISSING
------------- ----------
BIG GEAR               4 
CHAIN                  4 
PEDALS SET             8 
PEDALS                 3 
SMALL GEAR             4 
ALUMINUM BARS         46 
FRAME                  6 
BICYCLE               11 
SCREWS                22 
DRIVING UNIT           4 
CAR                    2
```

Comment: I'm still analyzing this code to understand how it works and though the code gives the expected result for the example I set, I have found that for the code in lines from 1 to 13, if the component is shared between multiple products, it calculates the multiplied factor for all these products. In other words if the composition table has two items named bicycle and motorbike, the first one has as child 100 screws and the second 500 screws, then the code (line 1 - 13) will output a first line : Bicycle - Screws - 50000 and a second line : Motorbike - Screws - 50000 both of which are wrong.

Comment: @IlyesFerchiou Updated - however, I would suppose that half the issue you are having is from the definition of the tables and that you are using generic component names to define the parent/child relationship; surely the screws used in bicycle pedals are not the same type of screws used in motorbikes.

Comment: this is just an example that is not real, my real example is very complex (thousand of hundreds of products) and many components are shared between many products. So that would means for that example that the screws are exactly the same !

Comment: The new code has become very complex and I'm afraid I can only query (cannot add anything to the database). I have managed to replace the code in lines 1 - 13 with another that gives me the correct result even with shared components and even when there are orders for components but I don't know how to insert it in the code. Can you check it and tell me if it is feasible without procedures or functions or packages ?  The code is live here : https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_DHOK74E2B5RDP0MR3O6DB5MZ9.html

Comment: @IlyesFerchiou The factors going down the tree is relatively simple (and is in my original edit) but you also need to calculate it going back up the tree (i.e. a pedals set contains 4 screws and a driving unit or a complete bicycle contains 8 screws); calculating that is non-trivial if you can have multiple paths to a component.